# How can I log every request/response body in Armeria HTTP client

Tags: http, logging, armeria

I tried two approaches to log every HTTP body produced/received by my armeria client:

1. using out-of-box [LoggingClient](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.linecorp.armeria/armeria-javadoc/latest/com/linecorp/armeria/client/logging/LoggingClient.html) decorator

```
decorator(LoggingClient.newDecorator())
```

2. creating custom logging decorator

```
decorator { delegate, ctx, req ->
        ctx.log().whenRequestComplete().thenAccept { log -> logger.trace(log.toStringRequestOnly()) }
        ctx.log().whenComplete().thenAccept { log -> logger.trace(log.toStringResponseOnly()) }
        delegate.execute(ctx, req)
    }
```

But I see in logs only headers and other technical information. How can I log requestContent/responseContent?

[It's said in armeria documentation](https://armeria.dev/docs/advanced-structured-logging) that these fields are available only for Thrift clients:

> the serialization-dependent content object of the request. ThriftCall for Thrift. null otherwise.
> the serialization-dependent content object of the response. ThriftReply for Thrift. null otherwise.

It's weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `com.linecorp.armeria.client.logging.ContentPreviewingClient` decorator in addition to logging decorator:

```
decorator(ContentPreviewingClient.newDecorator(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

LoggingClient is mostly for rpc requests. I had to use ContentPreviewingClient and access request-response payloads via requestContentPreview() and responseContentPreview()

Comment: `LoggingClient` is working at the HTTP level. So you can use it to log `requestContentPreview()`. The counterpart of ``LoggingClient` is `LoggingRpcClient` that is used for Thrift clients.